# How to manipulate SQL server from flutter app by using Firestore

Tags: sql, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have thousands of records in SQL server. I want to develop a flutter app with the Firestore. is there a way to implement interacting with these data from the app by Firestore. I know the flutter can work with Firestore smoothly. So I want to connect Flutter and SQL server by Firestore.  Basically, I want to develop a flutter app  with Firestore but data is existing in SQL server

Comment: "I want to connect Flutter and SQL server by Firestore." It's a bit unclear to me what that means. Where does the SQL server run? You can use Firebase Cloud Functions to make requests to another server. You might protect the SQL server by an REST API layer instead of exposing it directly to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am wondering if there are some firebase API can call the SQL server directly. in other words, I can make an Http request from the Flutter to a rest server including SQL directly without firebase, I think this can work well. However, I want to find another way that if there is a chance  I can call firebase function to interact with SQL directly without rest layer from flutter app.

Comment: Firebase itself has no relation to SQL server whatsoever. Firebase clould functions can make HTTP requests. That's about it. With SQL server do you mean the Microsoft SQL Server, or any SQL database?

Comment: Yes, It is MS SQL Server. You are right, If the firebase can call the SQL server, where the SQL should run. there should have a rest API to firebase can access in theory. Or can we import data from SQL server to firebase? is this possible, they are the different type of database. I do not know there is a way to convert these

Comment: "Or can we import data from SQL server to firebase?" You mean as a one-time action? That's theoretically possible, but Firebase is NoSQL and the data format incomatible in almost every possible way. You would completely restructure your data.

Comment: the one-time action is not what I am looking for. Actually, I want to sync the data all the time. So far, I think there is no other choice except for providing rest API. Thanks mate

Comment: Sounds like the way to go for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible however
You need to create an api so your app would connect through the api and then the api would react with the sql server and it goes on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).